# How to concatenate datetime SQL value if I received hour format in variable

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I get a variable `@time="6:00"` which I read from a cell in an Excel worksheet that has datetime datatype in a stored procedure, and store it in SQL database as datetime like this (`1900-01-01 06:00:00.000`) but now I'm reporting in SSRS and this doesn't serve me well.

Is there a way to update when I get the `@time` in hour format but also concatenate the date like this format `2020-03-04 + 06:00:00.000 = 2020-03-04 06:00:00.000`

Comment: can you just use CONCAT(CAST(getdate() AS date),  ' 06:00:00')?

Comment: well now I feel dumb, been at this for 2 hours....thank you, thank you!!!